# How do you compile Lua code on ESP8266 Board?

Tags: lua, nodemcu

The `node` module has a method named `compile` that compiles the code and creates .lc files.

Do I use a tool like `nodemcu-tool` to connect to the board via the `terminal` parameter, and execute `node.compile('myfile.lua')` commands to create `.lc` files?

If `init.lua` is compiled as `init.lc` upon reset will the board execute the compiled code?

Comment: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/compiling/ Apparently there's a luac.cross program that compiles Lua to byte code on your PC that you can then run on nodemcu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `init.lua` is compiled as `init.lc` upon reset will the board execute the compiled code?

Yes, as per our FAQ

> Note that if you use `require("XXX")` to load your code then this will automatically search for `XXX.lc` then `XXX.lua` so you don't need to include the conditional logic to load the bytecode version if it exists, falling back to the source version otherwise.

However, also note that your `init.lua` is expected to be fairly small with the actual application split into separate files loaded dynamically.

> (How) Do I use a tool like `nodemcu-tool` to connect to the board via the `terminal` parameter, and execute `node.compile('myfile.lua')` commands to create `.lc` files?

As per the [command reference](https://github.com/AndiDittrich/NodeMCU-Tool/blob/master/docs/CommandReference.md#upload-files):

`$ nodemcu-tool upload --port=/dev/ttyUSB0 myfile.lua --compile`

Answer (score 1):

> How do you compile lua code on ESP8266 Board?

That depends on the tools you use. The workflow I'd use is:

1. Upload Lua code to NodeMCU using `nodemcu-uploader`
2. Connect to the NodeMCU using `picocom`
3. Compile the file using `node.compile()`
4. (optional) Download the file again using `nodemcu-uploader`

Different tools may change the involved steps slightly, but overall the idea will remain the same:

upload -> compile (-> download)

> If init.lua is compiled as init.lc upon reset will the board execute the compiled code?

Try it ;)

If it doesn't work, you can always just write a one-line `init.lua` that require `init.lc`; it's not like that would impact your performance once your chip is booted and running.

Or you could just rename the compiled file to init.lua and it should also work.

But keep in mind, as the documentation says:

> [...] compilation is RAM-intensive and hence you will find that you will need to break your application [...]

Comment: Thank you very much for a sensible response and not berating me for posting what looks like a silly question.